# XPath count why doesn't it work instinctively?

Tags: xml, xpath, count, xquery

Straight to the point,

the database I'm using : 
     http://metalab.unc.edu/bosak/xml/eg/shaks200.zip

Query 1 :

```
count(db:open("shaks200","r_and_j.xml")//ACT)
```

Query 2 :

```
count(db:open("shaks200","r_and_j.xml")//ACT[.])
```

Query 1 gives as result 185, while Query 2 gives 5 as result.
5 is the correct answer, but why doesn't Query 1 give the correct answer ?

Comment: I just tried with IntelliJ and that gives `5` on both inputs. Huh.

Comment: We need to find out where that 185 is coming from. Select `//ACT` and inspect its contents, that will hopefully tell us what actually happens. Also, which version of BaseX?

Comment: 7.2.1, installed it today on windows. And I have no idea what to look for.. why would the [.] let it work.

Comment: Must be a bug in BaseX -- contact the developers (e.g. @ChristianGrün) and report it.

Comment: I agree, this can only be a bug.

Comment: Seems the document is ignored for count. Didn't find the bug examining it a few minutes, somebody knowing the XQuery core will dig into that within short time for sure. Forwarded the bug to the mailing list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the report and the referenced example files. The bug has been fixed in the [latest stable snapshot](http://files.basex.org/releases/latest/) and will also be available in the next official release (due end of this week).